# Wrong encoding from remote MSSQL in php using freetds,unixODBC

Tags: php, sql-server, centos, freetds, unixodbc

I finally managed to connect php in remote MSSQL 2008 server under CentOS. I installed Freetds and unixODBC on CentOS,configure odbc.ini,freetds.conf and odbcinst.ini and connection works like a charm.But my problem is that i have greek characters in MSSQL(greek collation) so when i do a SELECT through php,greek characters appeared like "?????".I tried to set

> client charset = UTF-8 in freetds.conf

or change

> tds version

but still nothing.
I would appreciate some help..